# useContext with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm following a (video) tutorial on YouTube on useContext

Switching from the legacy props flow to this, I'm a bit confused as to what children is in ProviderWrapper and why it needs to be passed in.

If children is SomeComponent2, why doesn't someObj appear as a prop on its own without having to use useContext? as it's wrapper by ProviderWrapper which is passing it through its value?

```
const SomeContext = createContext()

function ProviderWrapper ({children}) {
    const someObj = { 'something': 'someValue' }
    return <SomeContext.Provider value={{ someObj }}>{children}</SomeContext.Provider> 
}

const SomeComponent2 = (props) => {
    console.log('props', props)
    const PropsFromProvider = useContext(SomeContext)
    console.log('PropsFromProvider', PropsFromProvider)
    return null
}

function App() {
    return (
        <ProviderWrapper>
            <SomeComponent2 />
        </ProviderWrapper>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`children` here is mean to render whatever that is passed between `<ProviderWrapper>` tags which in your case is `<SomeComponent2 />`

As far as your thinking about `someObj` being available as props to SomeComponent2 is concerned, you should not that you are passing `{someObj}` to value prop of `<SomeContext.Provider>` which you must think of as the component holding the data and when you use `useContext` it will supply that data to the component using it

Think of this as similar to `Provider` component in react-redux if you would have used redux. In redux to access any redux value in a component you use `connect` with `mapStateToProps`, `useContext` here plays a similar role

An implementation of the above logic could be done without context, but using render props so that `SomeComponent2` is passed `someObj` as props like below

```
function ProviderWrapper ({children}) {
    const someObj = { 'something': 'someValue' }
    return children({someObj}); 
}

const SomeComponent2 = (props) => {
    console.log('props', props)
    return null
}

function App() {
    return (
        <ProviderWrapper>
            {(props) => <SomeComponent2 {...props}/>}
        </ProviderWrapper>
    );
}
```

However the limitation of the above logic is that it only is able to pass on the props directly to children. In order to access the props in a nested level, you need to pass them all the way down.

Comment: Please let me know if the above post helped you.

Answer (score 0):

From the reactJS doc, useContext get value from **nearest context provider**.
Normally what they do is

```
// You create a context
const SomeContext  = createContext();

// Then you wrap any component that need the value in it provider
<SomeContext.Provider value={{'something': 'someValue'}}>
    //Your component
</SomeContext.Provider>

// In any Your Component, You access the value by using useContext
function YourComponent() {
    const value = useContext(SomeContext);

    console.log(value); //You will get the Obj
    // It is not pass as Props
    ...
}
```

ProviderWrapper is just a wrapper so you can wrap any component that can access the **SomeContext**, so you no need to keep writing

```
<SomeContext.Provider value={{}}>
    //Your Component
</SomeContext.Provider>
```

Hope this make sense, and answer your question.
Correct me if im wrong

Comment: If I don't write a wrapper that returns <SomeContext.Provider value={{}}> what's the point of useContext(SomeContext) as there's nothing setting and passing values in SomeContext?

Comment: Sorry, that is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

> Switching from the legacy props flow to this, I'm a bit confused as to what children is in ProviderWrapper and why it needs to be passed in.

`children` is whatever child component you render inside a `<ProviderWrapper> ...children... </ProviderWrapper>`.  So in the example, yes it's `<SomeComponent2 />`.

> If children is SomeComponent2, why doesn't someObj appear as a prop on its own without having to use useContext? as it's wrapper by ProviderWrapper which is passing it through its value?

It could - you could just render `<SomeComponent2 something={somevalue} />`.  That would be the usual thing to do.

However what the tutorial is trying to demonstrate is how Context allows you can access values from a parent component *without* having to pass them down through props.  In the example, it's trivial, but imagine if "somevalue" was many levels higher up and each component was rendering another in a different file.  You would have to pass the value all the way down through many components, adding the `something` prop to each of them.  This is called "prop-passing" or "prop-drilling" and it means adding props that components have no need for, just for the sake of passing them down to some component that eventually needs them.

With Context, you simply render a Provider at some convenient place higher up and any component under it in the tree, at any depth, can consume its values.  That's useful for things like defining themes (e.g. "light" or "dark") so that components can render themselves appropriately without needing to add "theme" as a prop and passing it all the way down.